# How do I tell qBittorrent v4.3 to download files within a torrent sequentially? (files, not parts of files)

Tags: download, bittorrent, queue, qbittorrent

Normally qBittorrent will download many files simultaneously. Is there a way to tell it to use all bandwidth/connections to download one file and then move to the other?

Setting file priorities does help, but that's a lot of manual work, and two files with the same priority will be downloaded in parallel anyway.

This is not to start watching a video before it's downloaded fully! Its to finish downloading the 1 episode out of batch of 3.

Utorrent could do it easily, but new version of the program does not want to turn off ads fully as it did before, so i had to leave.

If there is absolutely no way qbittorrent can do this, please point me to a couple of other programs, small and fast, free, no ads.

UPD:
BiglyBT have the needed features, but something in the interface that doesnt fit.
I still hope to make qbittorrent do the trick, or try some other program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BiglyBT](https://www.biglybt.com/features.php)- Feature-filled Bittorrent client based on the Azureus open source project

[image: biglybt]

```
Fast, entirely open source and ad-free and features packed
```

And in my experience not small like qBittorrent but worth the compromise because of the features it provides

[Compare features with other torrent clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients#Features_I)

Detailed guide to set priority [Selective downloading in vuze](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Selective_downloading)

Edit - A gif of requested features

A better quality video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKLg7q-m6NnlLiayVMMjK5RgkEu9K0XT/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. BiglyBT has the needed function and good tree-like file/folder list but its interface is strange. Doesnt have some of needed columns - i need full size / size of chosen / downloaded / uploaded / remaining / status / down speed / up speed / date of finishing. It has only half of that... Advanced list of torrents opens second list of unknown purpose... At this point i prefer the qbittorrent and still hope to find all the necessary features in it or in other client.

Comment: @tio i edited my answer ; added  a gif showing requested feauteres ; will that solve your problem? Note that you can keep desired columns only ,no need to keep that long list of columns and if that helps feel free to upvote the answer !!!

Comment: It was a glitch or something, now i see all the columns. It almost solves it. Just something in the interface that bugs me. I will keep both qbittorrent and BiglyBT for now, but i want to try something else before settling.

Comment: the image link is dead. That's why it's recommended to use the internal image uploader of stackexchange that uploads to stack.imgur.com and never deletes the image

Answer (score -2):

Yes.
Select all the files > right click > Priority > Select By Shown file order